# Mergesort, using a for loop to do merge

Tags: c, mergesort

I am trying to write the code in C for `mergesort` using `for` loop in the merge function. Unfortunately it is not working.  In the `main` function I create an `array` on 10 `ints` in descending order and then I call the `mergesort` function to sort them. There is obviously an error in the merge function, since the ascending order is never realized and in some array sizes some long numbers intrude. What am I doing wrong? Here's the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void mergesort(int array[], int left, int right);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[10];
    for(i=10;i>0;i--){
        arr[10-i]=i;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
        }
    mergesort(arr,0,9);
    puts("\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}

void mergesort(int array[], int left, int right)
{
    void merge(int array[],int left, int mid, int right);
    int mid;
    if(left<right){
        mid=(left+right)/2;
        mergesort(array,left,mid);
        mergesort(array,mid+1,right);
        merge(array,left,mid,right);
    }
}

void merge(int array[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int i;
    int l=0;
    int r=mid+1;
    int arr_sorted[10];

    for(i=0;i<=right;i++){
        if((l<=mid) && (r<=right)){
            if(array[l]<array[r]){
                arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
                l++;
            }
            else {
                arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
                r++;
            }
        }
        if(l>mid){
            arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
            r++;
        }
        if(r>right){
            arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
            l++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=right;i++){
        array[i]=arr_sorted[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First that is looking strange is why you are passing `left` parameter to the `merge`, but iterate from `0` to `right`; `left` is not even using in this function.

Comment: I guess you need also iterate from left to right only in your loops. set i = left in your loops

Answer (score 3):

Some corrections that were needed in the merge function :

```
void merge(int array[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int i;
    int l=left; //If you are passing left, then it should be used here !!
    int r=mid+1;
    int arr_sorted[10];

    for(i=0;(l<=mid)&&(r<=right);i++){ 
//Your condition for this loop unnecessarily complicates the rest of the code. This is a better way to go about it
//The loop body is fine
       if(array[l]<array[r]){
                arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
                l++;
            }
            else {
                arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
                r++;
            }
        }

//Now, checking for remaining elements and adding them to the result
//The conditions are simple because of the test condition we used in the previous for loop
        if(l>mid){
           for(;r<=right;r++,i++) arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
        }
        if(r>right){
            for(;l<=mid;l++,i++)  arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=right;i++){
        array[i]=arr_sorted[i];
    }
}
```

Also, as a matter of style, try to keep your forward declarations in one place (more so as the functions are related). Instead of :

```
void mergesort(int array[], int left, int right)
{
    void merge(int array[],int left, int mid, int right);//This line should be moved to the top with the mergesort forward declaration
    int mid;
    if(left<right){
        mid=(left+right)/2;
```

Try doing :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void mergesort(int array[], int left, int right);
void merge(int array[],int left, int mid, int right); // <--------
```

This is just a matter of preference, though.

Comment: Fine but in the remaining elements section, how is the index i incremented and what values it takes? I tried it but it's not working

Comment: @Nick Ahh.. Yes i missed that. Check it now.

Answer (score 1):

here is the entire working merge sort, you can see the differences, let me know if you have any further questions. I had to change the name because stdlib has mergesort implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int mymergesort(int array[], int left, int right);

int main()
{
    int i;
    int arr[10];
    for(i=10;i>0;i--){
        arr[10-i]=i;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
        }

    mymergesort(arr,0,9);
    puts("\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}

int mymergesort(int array[], int left, int right)
{
    void mymerge(int array[],int left, int mid, int right);
    int mid;

    mid=(left+right)/2;
    if(left<right){
        mymergesort(array,left,mid);
        mymergesort(array,mid+1,right);
        mymerge(array,left,mid,right);
    }
    return 0;
}

void mymerge(int array[], int left, int mid, int right)
{
    int i=0;
    int l=left;
    int r=mid+1;
    int arr_sorted[10];

    for(i=left;i<=right;){
        if((l<=mid) && (r<=right)){
            if(array[l]<array[r]){
                arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
                l++;
                i++;

            }
            else {
                arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
                r++;
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(l>mid){
            for(;r<=right;r++){   
                arr_sorted[i]=array[r];
                i++;

            }   
            break;
        }
        if(r>right){
            for(;l<=mid;l++){

                 arr_sorted[i]=array[l];
                    i++; 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    for(i=left;i<=right;i++){
        array[i]=arr_sorted[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it. I just think that maybe the break command may not be needed. I still cannot figure out why my original version, except for the left assignments produced wrong results.

Comment: When u test your code for small cases, you ll clearly see where ur code fails and why, test for 3 elements. U strictly need to get each conditional block executed at a time, when it enters the first if block, it assigns appropriate value to the sorted array, then it enters the last if block and it changes in to a inappropriate value.  You strictly need to increase i every time you assign a value to arr_sorted

Comment: If i would like to test this code for large arrays of ints, say over a million, what changes should i make? I know I should use pointers, (my version of pointers gives implementation of 1.000.000 ints in 10 secs, which i think is too much), but how exactly?